# What is HDMI audio?

Tags: sound, hdmi

I see "Juniper HDMI Audio" under my sound devices list.

[image]

My question is, what is it and what does it do? Currently, adjusting the volume level does nothing. Google searches don't give a very clear explanation of it, other than that HDMI can "handle" audio.

Comment: Have you tried connecting audio device trough HDMI cable?

Comment: controls the audio-output through HDMI...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HDMI is a [video interface standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI) that combines electrical signaling for video and audio on one hot-pluggable cable (cable/connector designs aren't only about electrical differences but also their mechanical plug/unplug durability)

HDMI standard has the capability of carrying audio, but a device does not necessarily have to. For computers that offer the audio over HDMI, there is usually a secondary sound card (which may be only logically separated in the drivers) that is responsible for encoding the sound output in the format specified by HDMI.

The volume control will not affect anything unless you are playing sound through the HDMI port, you can think of the volume control as a "audio-out port" volume that will only work if there is something connected to that port.

So if you connect your laptop to the TV and set the TV to read audio from HDMI, the volume control is likely to work.

Answer (score 1):

HDMI it is port video-audio  its look like 
[image] 
u can plug it to a HDTV and on tv u have Video and sound from one cable.
 Your Ubuntu/Kubuntu can manage volume of this from this